# Batch file - extract variables to build complex query

Tags: batch-file, variables, for-loop

I've got a batch file I'm trying to modify which builds a wireshark capture, but specifically excludes IP traffic from a selection of IP addresses

As you can see from the original filter below, I'm trying to capture traffic from 2 subnets, but what I'd really like to do for each IP that I add to a list if build a 'ip src not %%IP%% and ip dst not %%IP%%' for each IP (which might be 15-20 IP addresses) rather than having to break it out by device type and iterate each one in turn.
I'm having trouble, as I'm trying to expand and concatenate strings in different ways.
My for loop isn't expanding the string of the IP list, and net1 and net2 aren't being expanded either - I'd like to make this really quite generic, as it's something I would want a number of different sites to use, all with different subnets and exclusion IPs

```
SETLOCAL EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion
set TSHARK="C:\Program Files (x86)\Wireshark\tshark"
set LOCATION = "E:\ISA_CAPTURE\"
set NAME = "ISA.pcapng"
set NET1 = 10.198.64
set NET2 = 10.198.63
set IP_LIST = 10.198.64.30 10.198.64 31,10.198.64.20 10.198.64.81
set "FILTER = net %NET1% and net %NET2% and not udp portrange 2530-2550 and"
for /f "tokens=* delims= " %%i in (%%IP_LIST%%) do set "FILTER=!FILTER! and   ip src not %%i and ip dst not %%i"
if not exist %LOCATION% mkdir %LOCATION%
%TSHARK% -i 1 -b filesize:50000 -b files:16000 -f %%FILTER%%" -w %LOCATION%%NAME%
```

The original version looked a bit like this - which is horrible to maintain.

```
if not exist %LOCATION% mkdir %LOCATION%
%TSHARK% -i 1 -b filesize:50000 -b files:16000 -f "net 10.28.57 and net 10.28.132 and ip src not 10.28.57.30 and ip dst not 10.28.57.30 and ip src not 10.28.57.32 and ip dst not 10.28.57.32 and ip src not 10.28.57.132 and ip dst not 10.28.57.132 and ip src not 10.28.57.133 and ip dst not 10.28.57.133 and ip src not 10.28.57.144 and ip dst not 10.28.57.144 and ip src not 10.28.57.146 and ip dst not 10.28.57.146 and ip src not 10.28.57.180 and ip dst not 10.28.57.180 and ip src not 10.28.57.183 and ip dst not 10.28.57.183 and ip src not 10.28.57.185 and ip dst not 10.28.57.185 and ip src not 10.28.206.26 and ip dst not 10.28.206.26 and not udp portrange 2530-2550" -w %LOCATION%%NAME%
```

Answer (score 0):

undone by formatting - I'd retyped the variables and forgotten which language I was using.

```
SETLOCAL  EnableDelayedExpansion
set TSHARK="C:\Program Files (x86)\Wireshark\tshark"
set LOCATION=E:\ISA_CAPTURE\
set NAME=ISA.pcapng
set net1=net 10.198.64
set net2=net 10.198.63
set net3=net 10.198.1
set ip_list= 10.198.64.30 10.198.64.31,10.198.64.20 10.198.64.81
set "FILTER=(%net1% or %net2% or %net3%) and not udp portrange 2530-2550"
for %%i in (%ip_list%) do set "FILTER=!FILTER! and ip src not %%i and ip dst not %%i"
if not exist %LOCATION% mkdir %LOCATION%
%TSHARK% -i 5 -b filesize:50000 -b files:16000 -f "%FILTER%" -w %LOCATION%%NAME%
```